# SAPUI5 table extension

Tags: sapui5

I am using a sap.ui.table.Table control and have added some controls in the 'extension' aggregation. Specifically, I have added a HorizontalLayout that has 2 buttons in it. However, both the buttons show up as left aligned. I tried changing the alignment but nothing seems to get them to show up on the extreme right.
Here is the code snippet:

```
     `<table:Table height="100%" width="100%">
        <table:extension>`
            <l:HorizontalLayout>
               <Button text="Save" />
               <Button text="Cancel"/>  
           </l:HorizontalLayout>
        </table:extension>
      </table:Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `HorizontalLayout` will be `left-aligned` only.
Why not use a `MatrixLayout` instead with a single cell and set its `hALign` property to `Right`?